# php for loop issue for writting to SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Can anyone help with the following issue?

The full code is here:- https://affectivevideo.co.uk/code/

Application - https://affectivevideo.co.uk/avs/

The clips are selected randomly from a dataset of 100  so it only lists 10 at random into a slider with a FilmID.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Films ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

We need to pull in the following results for each clip into the database.

```
('$_POST[$avalue]', '$_POST[$vvalue]', '$_POST[$filmid]', '$_POST[parnum]' )";
```

This is the current code I just don't know how to get the filmID in to enable writing it to the database.

```
$servername = "shareddb-u.hosting.stackcp.net";
$username = "cl57-avs-31333347a0";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "cl57-avs-31333347a0";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (PARNUM, EMAIL)
VALUES ('$_POST[parnum]', '$_POST[email]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "User record created successfully <br>";
} else {
 echo "User record error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

====WORKS to here===

$avalue = "Avalue";
$avalue = mysql_real_escape_string($avalue);
$vvalue = "Vvalue";
$vvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($vvalue);
$filmid = "film";
$filmid = mysql_real_escape_string($filmid);


for ($x = 1; $x <= 40; $x++) {

$raval = "$avalue$x";
$rvval = "$vvalue$x";
$rfilmid = "$filmid$x";

$sqlRes = "INSERT INTO Results ( AVALUE, VVALUE, FILMID, PARNUM) VALUES ('$_POST[$raval]', '$_POST[$rvval]', '$_POST[$rfilmid]', '$_POST[parnum]' )";

if ($conn->query($sqlRes) === TRUE) {
 echo "AV New record created successfully";
 echo "$raval , $rvval , $rfilmid"  . "<br />";
} else {
 echo "AV Error: " . $sqlRes . "</br>" . $conn->error;
}

}



print_r($_POST);

$conn->close();

?>
```

Old Code PHP 5.6. This worked when it was a random list of 40 videos every time. Now it is 10 random videos from 100. I think the issue is I don't have anything that I can match up the random clip number. 3 are currently being used for testing.

Results POST readout :-

New records created successfully

Array ( [email] => a@a.co.uk [parnum] => 3 [Avalue38] => 3 [Vvalue38] => 3 [Avalue7] => 1 [Vvalue7] => 1 [Avalue85] => 8 [Vvalue85] => 8 )

Update 17/07/2020 - based on waterloomatt comment

If I set the $_POST[Avalue??] in the example to one of the clip numbers "97" its posted the results to the DB. The issue I can't solve is how I get it to know what clips are being called and or run thought a counter of the optional 100 to narrow it down.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Results (AVALUE, VVALUE, FILMID, PARNUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $avalue, $vvalue, $filmid, $parnum);

$avalue = "$_POST[Avalue97]";
$vvalue = "$_POST[Vvalue97]";
$filmid = "$_POST[Clip97]";
$parnum = "$_POST[parnum]";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
```

User record created successfully
New records created successfully
Array ( [email] => shaunroberts100@googlemail.com [parnum] => 1 [Avalue97] => 9 [Vvalue97] => 9 [Avalue13] => 1 [Vvalue13] => 1 )

This writes one record for clip 97 but this is because I have manually assigned the number to the code.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` API; it is deprecated. Use either `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also, use prepared statements instead of directly injecting user supplied data into your queries.

Comment: Why are you escaping constant strings, which are not even used? Why are you mixing mysql with mysqli? How much of this code actually works?

Comment: See the 2 sections on `mysqli` and `pdo` - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Hi Waterleematt, I saw that mysql_* API; was deprecated. I am just not sure how to work the code to pull the 10 random Film ID to the SQL post. I will have a look at the post now.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have broken the code down to what works. When I work this originally it was PHP 5.6. So I have been updated the code which is half and half. I just can't figure out how to structure this last part to write the results to the database.